# Plotting slow over time-Android how to free the memory when a real time data is plotting using MPAndroidChart Line Graph?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am working on an Android application which is plotting the heart rate using a line graph. I am receiving a packet of data via UDP broadcast in every 65 milliseconds which I need to plot. The graph rendering is very smooth for the first 2-3 minutes and after that it getting slower. Could anyone help me to figure out what makes it getting slow over time? How to free up the memory while plotting large data?

```
private void addEntryGraph01(int ch0[], LineChart chart) {
    LineData data = chart.getLineData();
    if (data != null) {
        ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
        if (set == null) {
            set = createSet();
            data.addDataSet(set);
        }
        data.addXValue("");
        for (int i = 0; i < ch0.length; i++)
            data.addEntry(new Entry((float) (ch0[i]), set.getEntryCount()), 0);
        chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chart.setVisibleXRange(50, 50);
        chart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - 10);
        return;
    }
}

   private LineDataSet createSet() {
    LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "");
    set.setDrawCubic(true);
    set.setDrawValues(false);
    set.setCubicIntensity(0.1f);
    set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    set.setColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set.setCircleColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set.setLineWidth(1f);
    set.setDrawCircles(false);
    set.setFillAlpha(65);
    set.setFillColor(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
    set.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 177));
    set.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    set.setValueTextSize(10f);
    return set;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately MPAndroidChart is not supporting large amount of data.. So I choose a different plotting library..

Comment: According to their documentation and the demo application on Google play store, it supports large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

We ran a few tests to compare performance of [various Android Charting Libraries](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/) here, and MPAndroidChart came out second, but [SciChart for Android](http://scichart.com/android-chart-features) was first by a wide margin.

This is a new (commercial) charting component tailored for real-time use in Android Apps and Embedded Systems. It's a few days away from release so not available just yet but will be extremely soon!

[image]

*Disclosure: Please be advised I work on the SciChart Android project.*